# My approach On Handling Multiple User in oauth2Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm using this approach in handling multiple users in my own scheduling app. Please guide me is this approach good and follow industrial standards.Here for just development purpose I'm using array to store refresh tokens but soon I'll be storing it in database the code is follow:

```
app.get("/google/", async (req, res) => {
    const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
});
    res.redirect(url);
});
app.get("/google/redirect/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const code = req.query.code;
    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    token.push(tokens.refresh_token);
    return res.status(201).json("worked");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(400).json("bad request");
  }
});

app.post("/events", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.body.user === "a") {
      oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: token[0],
      });
  } else {
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: token[1],
    });
  }
  const { summary, location, description, start, end } = req.body;
  if (!summary || !location || !description || !start || !end) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .json(
        "Summary , location , description , Start Time  and End Time all are required"
      );
  }
  const startTime = moment(start, "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss a").format();
  const endTime = moment(end, "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss a").format();
  const event = {
    summary: summary,
    location: location,
    description: description,
    start: {
      dateTime: startTime,
      timeZone: "Asia/Karachi",
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: endTime,
      timeZone: "Asia/Karachi",
    },
  };
  const response = await calendar.events.insert({
    calendarId: "primary",
    auth: oauth2Client,
    resource: event,
  });
  res.send({ msg: "done", response });
});
```

I need advice as well as more tips from my fellow developers in this scenario because I know there's always room for improvement